# Need to parse headers in csv

Tags: java

I am trying to parse a csv having header as "Last Name, First Name, Address"
Now i have a class Employee where i have declared these properties as below:

```
import com.univocity.parsers.annotations.Parsed;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashcode
@ToString
public class Employee {

    @Parsed(index =0)
    @JsonProperty("Last Name")
    private String lastName;

    @Parsed(index =1)
    @JsonProperty("First Name")
    private String firstName;

    @Parsed(index =2)
    @JsonProperty("Address")
    private String address;
}
```

So while hitting the API: We are not able to parse the header

Error:
Required header row missing or has invalid values. Parsed values[Last Name, First Name, Address] Expected values[lastName, firstName, address]

Thanks in advance

> With this i tried with the other import for JsonProperty.
> I also tried creating explicit getter and setter removing the lombok annotation
> I also tried adding JsonProperty annotation on getters and not on the properties itself.

all while, i am encountering same issue.

Answer (score 1):

`JsonProperty` has nothing to do with `univocity.Parsed`.

According to the Univocity [doc](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.univocity/univocity-parsers/latest/index.html), you could try to use `field` attribute for `Parsed` like this:

```
@Parsed(field = "Last Name", index = 0)
private String lastName;
```